# Compute the second weak derivative of $f(x) = log(x) \: \text{ for } x\in (0,1), f(x) = 0 \: \text{ for }x \in (-1,0)$

Tags: logarithms, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $f(x) = log(x) \: \text{for } x \in (0,1)
 \text{ and } 0 \text{ for } x \in (-1,0) 
$. Compute the second weak derivative of $f$. In the lecture we computed the first weak derivative using a principal-value integral as:
\begin{equation}
\langle \partial T_{f}, \phi \rangle = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)}{x} dx \: \forall \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)
\end{equation}

As an exercise (not to be handed in) we should compute the second weak derivative of $f$.
The solution should be:
\begin{equation}
\langle \partial^{2} T_{f}, \phi \rangle = \phi'(0) + \phi(0)+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0) - x\phi'(0)}{x^2} dx
\end{equation}

It is also not clear to me why the last integral should be finite, since $\phi$ is not supposed to be real analytic, so we cannot use Taylor.

My idea would be the following:
\begin{equation}
\langle \partial^2 T_{f}, \phi \rangle = -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi'(x)- \phi'(0)}{x} dx
\end{equation}
So first shifting one derivative to $\phi$ and then applying all the previous arguments. I don't see why this doesn't work but it doesn't give the desired result.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Thanks @md2perpe I edited the post

Comment: Your idea is a good beginning. Now integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @md2perpe for the help. I think I have the answer now.

integrating by parts, we get:
\begin{equation}
-(\frac{\phi(x) - x\phi'(o)}{x}) \bigg {|}_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(x) - x \cdot \phi'(0)}{x^2} dx
\end{equation}

Now, by adding $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\phi(0)}{x}$ and subtracting it again, we can make make both terms well-defined:
\begin{equation}
\phi(1) + \underbrace{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}(\frac{\phi(\epsilon) - \phi(0)}{\epsilon})}_{\phi'(0)} -  - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0) -  x \cdot \phi'(0)}{x^2} dx
\end{equation}

which is the desired expression. The last integral is well-defined since $\phi$ is assumed to be inifinitely, and thus also twice differentiable.

Comment: Is there any other primitive function to $\phi'(x)-\phi'(0)$ than $\phi(x)-\phi'(0)x$?

Comment: Remember that you can add a constant to your primitive function. Choose it wisely!